# Tab Item and Tab Control Border Style

Tags: wpf

How do I style the Tab Control Border so that the selected Tab Item does not have a line underneath it?

[image: WPF Tab Item]

These are my Tab Control and Tab Item styles so far.

```
<!-- Tab control styling -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,5" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3.5" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
        </Style>
        <!-- Tab item styling -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border 
                                 Name="Border"
                                 Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
                                 BorderBrush="Black" 
                                 BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" 
                                 CornerRadius="3,3,0,0"
                                 MinWidth="120">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        ContentSource="Header"
                                        Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

If I can achieve the look displayed in the screenshot without having to overload the tab item control template then I don't have an issue as the default tab item template doesn't have the line underneath it on the selected tab. I haven't been able to do this so far. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the only option you have is to overwrite the tabcontrol template

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I probably will have to overload the tabcontrol template. I just don't know how I would draw the top line of the tabcontrol border so that it has a line but that line is not visible underneath the selected tabitem. Maybe the tabitem template could overlay the tabcontrol by 1 pixel allowing me to control tabitem bottom border line visibility via the tabitem template. Not currently sure what the xaml to do that would look like assuming it's possible.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The XAML below is how I have overridden the TabControl to solve this problem.  The key piece of info is the `Margin` property of the `HeaderPanel`.  You will see that the bottom margin is -1, which shifts it down just enough to cover up that line.

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Panel.ZIndex="1"
                              Margin="0,0,4,-1"
                              IsItemsHost="True"
                              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                              Background="Transparent" />

                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">

                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                        </Border.Background>

                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                          Margin="4"
                                          ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Won't that hide the bottom line for all the `TabItems` instead of only the selected `TabItem`?

Comment: No, it doesn't, because the current TabItem is on top of the other TabHeaders.  It works very smoothly.  (Been using it for a couple of years that way).

Comment: This was very helpful. Assigning -1 in the bottom margin really did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying (and failing!) with some very convoluted alternative solutions - this is almost comically simple. Much appreciated.

Comment: Don't understand how it can work. I've put the -1 margin and a ZIndex of 100 on the selected tabItem to make it hide this line.

Comment: I hate that this is the right answer...  Microsoft's default styles are the antithesis of what they're supposed to be doing.

Comment: Great answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Add property `Padding="0,0,0,0"` to tab control :-)

Comment: Actually setting it to -1 works much better:  Padding="-1"

Comment: I don't see any difference from Padding="0" or Padding="-1"

Answer (score 4):

Instead of modifying tabcontrol template, you may as well just modify the TabItem template, by adding two lines to cover up the border, and using minus margins for covering up.

(Please take a look at "TopLineCover" and "BottomLineCover" borders.)

[image]

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource VsBrush.WindowText}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="HeaderBorder" Padding="8,3,8,3" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"
                            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static commonControls:ColorService.JobViewHeaderBrushKey}}" 
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static commonControls:ColorService.JobViewHeaderBorderBrushKey}}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                                          />
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="TopLineCover" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Margin="0,-2,0,0" Height="3" Panel.ZIndex="100"
                            Background="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static commonControls:ColorService.JobViewHeaderBorderBrushKey}}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <Border x:Name="BottomLineCover" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" Margin="1,0,1,-2" Panel.ZIndex="100" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="HeaderBorder" Value="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="TopLineCover" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="BottomLineCover" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've accomplished this by making the `TabItem` extend a little further down then it's allocated, so its actually drawn on top of the border element and hides it

I can't remember how I did it exactly, but I think it was with a negative margin on the bottom of the `TabItem`